# ctypes dll loading is very slow

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

I am using ctypes to load a dll to control a Measurement Computing MiniLab board. It works, but takes about 5 seconds to load.

Is there a way to make this faster?

The library contains about 100 functions of which I am only using one. Can I maybe tell ctypes to load only that function or something like that?

```
import ctypes

class DaqInterface(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dll = ctypes.WinDLL("cbw64.dll")

    def set_analog(self, data, channel=0, board_num=0):
        res = self.dll.cbAOut(ctypes.c_int(board_num), ctypes.c_int(channel), ctypes.c_int(0), ctypes.c_int(data))
        if res != 0:
            raise RuntimeError("Daq error: {}".format(res))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    daq_interface = DaqInterface()
    daq_interface.set_analog(512)
```

The library: [Universal Library](http://www.mccdaq.com/daq-software/universal-library.aspx)
The interface: [miniLAB 1008](http://www.mccdaq.com/usb-data-acquisition/miniLAB-1008.aspx)

Comment: Its `DllMain` entrypoint apparently has 5 seconds of initialization work to do, or maybe it's just waiting for some event that never occurs. I'd attach a debugger and figure out what's taking so long.

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't be incrementing the DLL reference count for every instance of your class. Load it only once as a class variable. Also, `c_int` is the default argument conversion for integers, so you can simplify the call to just `self.dll.cbAOut(board_num, channel, 0, data)`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about that it could be the library that takes so long, but I tested it and it is. Debugging the library probably isn't that easy because it is closed source. I tried loading the library in a separate thread which didn't make a difference, maybe because of the GIL, I don't know how that is handled with ctypes. I do use a class variable now, that's a good suggestion.

Comment: Calling `LoadLibraryW` using ctypes will release the GIL to another thread, e.g. `kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32');` `kernel32.LoadLibraryW.restype = ctypes.c_void_p;` `hdll = kernel32.LoadLibraryW(u"cbw64.dll");` `DaqInterface.dll = ctypes.WinDLL("cbw64.dll", handle=hdll)`.